# Remove black line above references apsrev4

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I'm using `revtex4` as my document class and `apsrev4` as my bib style. I would like to remove the horizontal black line above the references.

How can I do this? Here's what I have without the text:

```
\documentclass[aps,12pt,tightenlines]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx,topcapt,booktabs,SIunits,units,mhchem}


\begin{document}
\bibstyle{apsrev4}
\bibliography{research}

\pagestyle{plain}





\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. To what black line do you refer? Perhaps a screen shot would help

Comment: Please add your code to the post window above, not as a comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it)

Comment: That code does not produce the output posted or reproduce the error. Please read the link Christian Hupfer included in the first comment.

Comment: All I did was remove the text from my file. It isn't an error, the line is supposed to be there. I simply would like to remove it for this paper.

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the *line* because it contains no text. Please read the link. Your example needs to illustrate what you would like to change.